# LOG_COUNT/ERROR shows more errors than actually occurred

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

So I have a spider that scrapes a site then emails me a file with the full logs of the run when it finishes. However, the Scrapy stats dump print out shows more errors than actually occurred. Here's what it says.

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 6346768,
'downloader/request_count': 8387,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 8387,
'downloader/response_bytes': 235756344,
'downloader/response_count': 8387,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 8387,
'dupefilter/filtered': 372,
'elapsed_time_seconds': 50357.631091,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 16, 15, 14, 57, 111264),
'item_scraped_count': 106752,
'log_count/DEBUG': 115513,
'log_count/ERROR': 6,
'log_count/INFO': 9761,
'memusage/max': 124174336,
'memusage/startup': 57204736,
'request_depth_max': 154,
'response_received_count': 8387,
'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 8386,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 8386,
'scheduler/enqueued': 8386,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 8386,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 16, 1, 15, 39, 480173)}
2020-12-16 15:15:01,746 - scrapy.core.engine - INFO - Spider closed (finished)
```

It says I had 6 errors, but I did ctrl-f on my log file and found nothing. Does anyone know why this might have happened? I have the logger set to record INFO and higher, and my log file only has the INFO logs. Here's the code for my logger.

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

consolehandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consolehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
consolehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

filehandler = logging.FileHandler('tmp/logs.txt')
filehandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

root.addHandler(consolehandler)
root.addHandler(filehandler)
```

Comment: This question no question mark? What do you want to know? How to get more errors into your log?

Comment: I want to know why the stats dump mentions more errors than actually occurred. I will edit my question to make it clearer. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: you really want to ask the right question. "Does anyone know why this might have happened?". The answer is either "Yes, someone knows" or "No, nobody knows". Neither of which brings you forward.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49353396/480982

Comment: No, unfortunately. The asker had a `spider_exceptions` part of their stats dump that I don't.

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the issue without requests, or were just a few, to see if the number changes?

Comment: @Gallaecio To be honest, I kinda forgot about this question. I did eventually find where the errors were coming from by sitting around and watching the logs as they came into the console. For some reason, the errors were being printed (like scraped items are) instead of being handled by the logger. I never found a solution to that, but I did fix the actual error (if i remember correctly, it was a possible but rare divide by zero in my pipeline due to some numbers i was scraping).